# What are familia metals for?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

I keep getting "familia metals" in the new event but I don't know what they are used for since they aren't in the event's 3 currencies

Answer (score 1):

Familia medals are used for the "event" gacha.

Go to Shop->Event Exchange->[supported Event]->Gacha to play to get Falna, Exilla Books, gacha gtd tickets, and other unique prizes.